# How to restore or install Nuget packages from copy then paste to *.csproj file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview - Version 16.8.0 Preview 2.0 , .NET Core `5.0.100-preview.8.20417.9` , ASP.NET Core 5.0-preview Web API.
Original file `*.csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Then I add (copy a part from another projects manually)

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Polly" Version="3.5.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="ChilkatNativeLib" Version="9.5.0.83" />
    <PackageReference Include="HtmlAgilityPack" Version="1.11.24" />
    <PackageReference Include="HtmlAgilityPack.NetCore" Version="1.5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="5.0.0-preview.8.20414.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0-preview.8.20414.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="5.0.0-preview.8.20414.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0-preview.8.20407.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.0-preview.8.20407.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.0-preview.8.20407.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core" Version="5.0.0-preview.8.20414.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.0-preview.8.20419.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MimeKit" Version="2.9.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NAudio" Version="1.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.11.5-alpha.0.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="SendGrid" Version="9.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.10.0-dev-01240" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations" Version="5.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="5.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="5.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="5.5.1" />

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.10.9" />

    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Syndication" Version="5.0.0-preview.8.20407.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages" Version="5.0.0-preview.8.20407.11" />

  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Then I run

```
dotnet restore
```

but not success.

How to restore or install Nuget packages from copy then paste to `*.csproj` file?

Comment: What does happen when you restore?

Comment: this is my result https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/6dd75211b61e8161a9d0d68e48a87783 and https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/91710885-2c1b1d00-ebaf-11ea-938b-e125a3c2c4ae.png

Comment: Please run this command " Update-Package –reinstall "   in your package manager console and check again.

Comment: this is my result https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/91711140-96cc5880-ebaf-11ea-84c1-c9143e87bc37.png

Comment: Did you rebuild your solution ?

Comment: Yes, I tried F5 (debug), build, but still see yellow triagles at NuGet dependencies.

Comment: Is your project building successfully or not ? could you take image from error (if you have) ?

Comment: buid and run success, but when I using a class or method from dependency, It show error.

Comment: What is that error ?

Comment: @DoNhuVy,  this is actually an issue on vs 2019 preview for `net core 5.0`.And I have tested this issue on other different agents. Since `net core 5.0` is still in the testing phase, and there are still many problems. This problem is understandable, but thank you for discovering and reporting this problem.

Comment: @DoNhuVy, since this is the actual issue, I suggest you could `accept my answer` and you could also follow the link from my answer to trace the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to restore or install Nuget packages from copy then paste to
> *.csproj file?

**I think it is an issue on Visual Studio Preview 16.8 with Net Core 5.0.**

**First of all**, `update-package -reinstall` command cannot be used for Net Core project, it is used for Net Framework projects with [packages.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config) nuget management format.

For **Net Core** projects, you can just click build which will restore nuget packages.

**Actually**, when you install the nuget package on the **Net Core 5.0** project, it restores packages successfully on the global nuget folder.

You can first delete all nuget packages under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages` and then rebuild your project.

The packages will all restore under that folder.

====================================================================

**But however, the main issue is that:**

For `Net Core 5.0`, nuget package has no name and reference path though it can be restored and build without any warnings and errors.

[image]

While in `Net Core 3.1,` it has the name and full reference path so that VS can find it.

[image]

That's why the yellow triangle occurs. And not sure whether this behavior will affects your developing.

And the **name** and **path** are the given by the system and we cannot change it.

You can try to change your project from `Net Core 5.0` to `Net Core 3.1`, I am sure that most of the yellow triangles will disappear.

**Since it is an issue**, [I have reported it to our DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1169297/there-are-yellow-triangles-on-the-nuget-packages-w.html).

You can vote it or add any comments if I did not describe the issue in detail. And I hope **the Team** will check the issue and resolve the issue as soon as possible.